# Render symbolic link without redirecting

Tags: .htaccess

I want `/rss-2/` to be reached at `/rss/news.php` (this file does not exist) `/rss-2/` currently shows the feed (generated by a wp plugin), I want to show it on the other page as well.

I tried

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /rss/news.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /rss-2/ [R]
```

but I couldn't find an appropriate flag that renders the destination instead of redirecting to it.

Comment: Just use `[L]` or use no flag at all ;-)

Comment: Does not work. Some other ruleset is overriding it. :|

Comment: Actually, you mention wordpress. Wordpress looks at the url in the address bar, not how you rewrite the url. You can use the `[P]` flag to proxy the request, but I heard this is quite expensive since you are doing an additional request to your own server with that url. The second request will see rss-2 and will handle it accordingly, which will pass it on to request 1 which will show it to the user. I am not familiar enough with wordpress to know if you can do it otherwise.

Comment: I'll accept this as solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'll post it as an actual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress looks at the url in the address bar, not how you rewrite the url. You can use the `[P]` flag to proxy the request, but I heard this is quite expensive since you are doing an additional request to your own server with that url. The second request will see rss-2 and will handle it accordingly, which will pass it on to request 1 which will show it to the user. Additionally, the proxy connection has to be set up for each request.

See [this page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/proxy.html) for more information.